# jpa , Hibernate, Spring data jpa and repositories

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-repositories

Hi guys I know that hibernate is a jpa implementation and spring data jpa is an abstraction of access to jpa data, but I need to know the relation between them how does they work.

Comment: Please, explain what exactly you are looking for. Otherwise this question won't get any useful answer and probably get closed, real quick.

You already described their relation. And if you generally ask how they work, the proper answer would be links to their respective source repositories.

Comment: For exemple I want to add a new client to my database so what will happen exactly I want to know the steps !!